# Ruby's File.open gives "No such file or directory - text.txt (Errno::ENOENT)" error

Tags: ruby

I installed Ruby 1.9.2 on my Win 7 machine. Created a simple `analyzer.rb` file. It has this one line:

```
File.open("text.txt").each {|line| puts line}
```

When I run the code, it gives me this error:

```
analyzer.rb:1:in `initialize': No such file or directory - text.txt (Errno::ENOENT)
from analyzer.rb:1:in `open'
from analyzer.rb:1:in `<main>'
Exit code: 1
```

I don't get it. There is a `text.txt` file in the same directory as the `analyzer.rb` file. I also tried feeding the absolute path of the file, `C:\Ruby192\text.txt`, but no dice. What am I missing?

Comment: For those of us who blindly googled this based on an error from a script, it can mean that the file you are looking for does not exist! If your code didn't check for file existence that may be your whole problem.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Start by figuring out what your **current working directory** is for your running script.
Add this line at the beginning:

`puts Dir.pwd`.

This will tell you in which current working directory ruby is running your script. You will most likely see it's not where you assume it is. Then make sure you're specifying pathnames properly for windows. See the docs here how to properly format pathnames for windows:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html

Then either use `Dir.chdir` to change the working directory to the place where text.txt is, or specify the absolute pathname to the file according to the instructions in the IO docs above. That SHOULD do it...

**EDIT**

Adding a 3rd solution which might be the most convenient one, if you're putting the text files among your script files:

```
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

This will automatically change the current working directory to the same directory as the `.rb` file that is running the script.

Comment: That was it. Dir.pwd did the trick. It was looking at C:\Ruby192 whereas I was putting the text file into C:\Ruby192\bin. Once I placed it in the correct location, it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @enraged camel: You generally shouldn't be putting text files there. The more you muck around with files there, the more likely you're going to delete something you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks! Had the same issue with Nagios running the ruby script in background... `Dir.chdir` did the trick!

Answer (score 13):

`ENOENT` means it's not there.

Just update your code to:

```
File.open(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/text.txt').each {|line| puts line}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That didn't seem to help however. Still getting the same error, even though text.txt exists in the Ruby installation directory right next to the .rb file. What are some possible reasons it may not be finding it?

Comment: Actually the best solution might be `Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))`. That way you will guarantee the working directory is the same as the script.

Comment: You can also use `File.open(File.expand_path(__FILE__, `... as suggested in https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4656#issuecomment-131212402

Answer (score 6):

Please use `chomp()` or `chomp()` with STDIN

i.e. test1.rb

```
print 'Enter File name: '

fname = STDIN.gets.chomp()  # or fname = gets.chomp()


fname_read = File.open(fname)

puts fname_read.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
Dir.glob(".")
```

To see what's in the directory (and therefore what directory it's looking at).

Answer (score 2):

Next to being in the wrong directory I just tripped about another variant:

I had a `File.open(my_file).each {|line| puts line}` exploding but there was something by that name in the directory I was working in (ls in the command line showed the name). I checked with a `File.exists?(my_file)`
which strangely returned `false`. Explanation: `my_file` was a symlink which target didn't exist anymore! Since `File.exists?` will follow a symlink it will say `false` though the link is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Ditto Casper's answer:

```
puts Dir.pwd
```

As soon as you know current working directory, specify the file path relatively to that directory.

For example, if your working directory is project root, you can open a file under it directly like this

```
json_file = File.read(myfile.json)
```