# How do I read from a file in the same directory?

Tags: ruby

I'm very much a beginner. I'd like to learn to read and write a file. Here's what I'm trying.

```
rdfile = File.open('bhaarat.txt', 'r+')
```

Unfortunately, this is returning "C:/directoriesblahblah/ubuntu3.rb:1:in 'initialize': No such file or directory - bhaarat.txt (Errno::ENOENT)

I have found solutions but I am not only new to Ruby but new to programming in general so I couldn't get an answer that made sense to me out of those.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19):

To obtain the path to the current file, you can use:

```
__FILE__
```

To obtain the directory in which the current file exists, you can use:

```
File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

To create a path from strings, you can use:

```
File.join('part1', 'part2', ...)
```

Therefore, to create a path to a file in that directory, you can use:

```
File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'filename')
```

If your file name is `bhaarat.txt`, the above becomes:

```
File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'bhaarat.txt')
```

If you replace that in your code, you will get:

```
rdfile = File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'bhaarat.txt'), 'r+')
```

You can also make this a separate variable, if you want, to make the code more readable:

```
path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'bhaarat.txt')
rdfile = File.open(path, 'r+')
```

Comment: I printed Dir.pwd and it was searching the wrong directory! So I guess one needs to make sure it's the right directory first. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The file is searched in the current directory, not the directory where the script is located.

```
C:\> ruby scripts\ubuntu3.rb
No such file or directory - bhaarat.txt
```

Move to the file location first and then run the script. For example, if the file is located in the same directory with the script:

```
C:\> cd scripts
C:\scripts> ruby ubuntu3.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'filename'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Found something that did the trick. Searched a little harder and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566884/rubys-file-open-gives-no-such-file-or-directory-text-txt-errnoenoent-er"):

I changed my original code

```
rdfile = File.open('bhaarat.txt', 'r+')
```

to

```
rdfile = File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'bhaarat.txt'), 'r+')
```

and that makes it look in the directory of your .rb file, instead of the directory that your command prompt is currently in.