# Rails app can no longer download a text file after upgrading to Rails 3.2.11 - no file found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*Short version* (TLDR):
**The download_file script below works fine in Rails 3.2.6, but does NOT in Rails 3.2.11.**

*Long version:*

I used to have a nice working download text file feature, but now when I try the action, I get this:

```
This webpage is not found 
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:3000/file_download
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.
```

My routes.rb has the correct /file_download route specified. I hadn't changed anything except move my Rails version up to 3.2.11. My script for downloading hadn't changed either; it's still this:

```
def download_file
    filename = 'my_memories.txt'
    file = File.open(filename, 'w') # creates a new file and writes to it

    current_user.memories.order('date DESC').each do |m|
      # Write the date, like 1/21/2012 or 1/21/2012~
      file.write m.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
      file.write '~' unless m.exact_date
      file.write " #{m.note}" if m.note
      file.puts

      # Write the content
      file.puts m.content
      file.puts # extra enter
    end

    send_file file
    file.close # important, or no writing will happen
    File.delete(filename)
  end
```

The error I see in my console is this:

```
ERROR Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - my_memories.txt
```

And I have looked at [Ruby's File.open gives "No such file or directory - text.txt (Errno::ENOENT)" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566884/rubys-file-open-gives-no-such-file-or-directory-text-txt-errnoenoent-er) and tried that solution, but that didn't work: I would get a different error

```
private method `puts' called for #<String:0x00000104551838>
```

if I did

```
puts Dir.pwd.
```

at the beginning of the download file method.

What could be going wrong? Things worked fine up till the Rails version change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out an answer to my problem, partly thanks to the person here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9086

Basically, send_file was being abused before (I saw the old method somewhere online). A file path should be passed.

Working code:

```
  def download_file
    filepath = "#{Rails.root}/public/downloaded_memories/my_memories.txt"

    file = File.open(filepath, 'w') # creates a new file and writes to it

    current_user.memories.order('date DESC').each do |m|
      # Write the date, like 1/21/2012 or 1/21/2012~
      file.write m.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
      file.write '~' unless m.exact_date
      file.write " #{m.note}" if m.note
      file.puts

      # Write the content
      file.puts m.content
      file.puts # extra enter
    end

    send_file filepath # make sure to send the file path, not the file name
    file.close # important, or no writing will happen
    # File.delete(filepath) # cannot delete this since the request would not then try to send a file path that doesn't exist
  end
```

Comment: A perhaps better way would be to use send_data instead of send_file altogether.

Comment: I am having challenges with send_file myself as I learn how to do this. Where are you placing this method? I have a model called Resource.rb with a column called "document". I would like to navigate to a resource and download the associated document. I have placed a similar download_file method in the ResourcesController, but I am getting an error when I click on the link saying that: Couldn't find Resource without an ID. Thanks for your help.