# Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__)) throws Errno::ENOENT

Tags: ruby, methods, relative-path, enoent

I got a method where I use `Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))` inside. I am using it so that I can run the ruby file from anywhere and not get this error: `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - 'filename' (Errno::ENOENT)`.

Using the method for the first time works fine but using it for the second time throws an error. See method and exact error below.

```
def meth(string)
  Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  hash = JSON.parse(File.read("file.json"))
  # do something with hash and string
  # return some value
end

meth("first string")   # this returns what is expected
meth("second string")  # this second usage of the method throws the error
```

Error sample pinpointing the line where I used `Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))`:

> dir/decoder.rb:44:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_s_chdir - lib (Errno::ENOENT)

Not sure if OS plays a role here, I am using an m1 BigSur on version 11.2.3.

- Why is this happening?
- What needs to be done so that the method` can be used as much as needed without running into the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby's File.open gives "No such file or directory - text.txt (Errno::ENOENT)" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566884/rubys-file-open-gives-no-such-file-or-directory-text-txt-errnoenoent-er)

Comment: No but that is the place where I found `Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here seems to be that `__FILE__` is a relative path like `dir/decoder.rb` and that path becomes invalid after the first time `Dir.chdir` is used, because that command changes the working directory of your entire Ruby process.  I think the solution would be to do something like this in your `decoder.rb` file:

```rb
DecoderDir = File.realpath(File.dirname(__FILE__))

def meth        
  Dir.chdir(DecoderDir)
  # ...
end
```

I'm guessing that the first time the Ruby interpreter processes the file, that is early enough that the relative path in `__FILE__` still refers to the right place.  So, at that time, we generate an absolute path for future use.

By the way, a well-behaved library should not run `Dir.chdir` because it will affect all use of relative paths throughout your entire Ruby process.  I pretty much only run `Dir.chdir` once and I run it near the beginning of my top-level script.  If you're making a reusable library, you might want to do something like this to calculate the absolute path of the file you want to open:

```
DecoderJson = File.join(DecoderDir, 'file.json')
```

Comment: Your solution worked!
I also found another alternative to what I was trying to do. Turns out using `require_relative 'filename'` was the simplest way to go.